# Store the content of an HTML element into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, variables, store, input-field

I want to store the content of a `span` element into a PHP variable. I want to use this in a relationship to the editable content tag. So that I finally have something like an input field. (In my project, I don't want to use normal input fields)

Thank you

Comment: why did i get a dislike?

Comment: If you're needing to get values from a contenteditable element that is not a form element, you need to consider using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

"something like an inputfield"
You can use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="yourname" value="thevalue" />
```

Hidden property sets this will not be visible
http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-hidden-tag.htm

Comment: If the answer solves it, accept it by clicking a huge check button on the left of the answer until it turns green.

Comment: Thank you @AminahNuraini